# How to get this specific field in firebase? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the documents from the bookings collection which have the "endDate" greater than DateTime.now(), but for some reason I am not getting any results out of it. I am able to get all the documents in the bookings collection, but I want it to be filtered as mentioned.

[image]

I tried retrieving it using this code

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .collection("bookings").where("booking").where("endDate", isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            List<Column> clientWidgets = [];
            
              final clients = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
              for (var client in clients!) {
                final clientWidget = Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              height:
                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: Image.network(client["booking"]
                                    ["restaurantImage"] ??
                                        ImageURLConstants.errorImage)
                                        .image,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: const Color(0xFF000000)
                                          .withOpacity(0.25),
                                      spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                      blurRadius: 4.5,
                                      offset: const Offset(0, 2.5))
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                height: double.infinity,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                    colors: [
                                      ApplicationColors
                                          .scaffoldBackgroundColor
                                          .withOpacity(0),
                                      ApplicationColors
                                          .scaffoldBackgroundColor
                                          .withOpacity(0.7),
                                      ApplicationColors
                                          .scaffoldBackgroundColor
                                          .withOpacity(1.0)
                                    ],
                                    stops: const [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      client["booking"]["restaurantName"] ??
                                          "",
                                      style: TextStyles.cardHeading,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                              .spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(children: [
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons
                                                    .calendar_today_outlined,
                                                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                                size: 16.0,
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                                              Text(
                                                DateFormat('EEE, d MMM y',
                                                    'en_US')
                                                    .format(DateTime.parse(
                                                    client["booking"][
                                                    "startDate"] ??
                                                        "")),
                                                // "25th Feb, 2023",
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color:
                                                    Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          height: 20,
                                          width: 50,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                width: 0.5,
                                                color: client["booking"]
                                                ["paid"] ==
                                                    1
                                                    ? const Color(
                                                    0xFF1A7026)
                                                    : const Color(
                                                    0xFFC71D1D),
                                              ),
                                              borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(
                                                  40)),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              client["booking"]["paid"] == 1
                                                  ? const Text(
                                                "Paid",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color(
                                                        0xFF1A7026)),
                                              )
                                                  : const Text(
                                                "Unpaid",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color(
                                                        0xFFC71D1D)),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );

                clientWidgets.add(clientWidget);
              }
            

            return clientWidgets.isEmpty
                ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: ApplicationColors.offWhite,
                      fontSize: 108.0),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'No bookings done yet',
                  style: TextStyles.greyText,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 120.0,
                ),
              ],
            )
                : ListView(children: clientWidgets);
          }),
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: u can do it because u have the string in DB, not a date, probably you can try edit your firebase documents and replase string into Date

Answer (score 0):

As WebFox commented, you've stored the date values as strings in the database, and then filter them with this condition:

```
where("endDate", isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
```

The `DateTime.now()` returns a `DateTime` object, which cannot be compared to the string values in the database. Or you *can* compare them, it'll just never be true.

To fix the problem, convert the date in the filter to a string in the same format too with:

```
where("endDate", isGreaterThan: DateTime.now().toIso8601String())
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion. I tried doing it but it still doesn't show anything!

I even tried changing it from string to timeStamp in firebase but it still doesn't show any results

Comment: First things first: does it make sense what I explained in my answer that you're comparing `DateTime()` values with a string and why that won't work? Does it also make sense how generating an ISO string could solve that problem? --- If those makes sense and you can't get it to work, did you check the string that is generted by `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()` and how it compares to the value in your database? Is there indeed a document with a `endDate` value greater than that? If so, please edit your question to show the updated code and the document you'd expect to get back.

Comment: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(): 2023-04-07T13:37:18.385562
startDate: 2023-04-05T11:15:55.702069
endDate: 2023-04-05T11:15:55.702069

This is my current output.. I am putting this as my query
"
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                  .collection("bookings")
                  .where("booking")
                  .where("endDate", isGreaterThan: DateTime.now().toIso8601String())
                  .snapshots(),
"